# Having trouble accessing element in object returned from get request in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

I've got a get request returning an array of objects taken from a database using Knex, I want to return them using .map giving them accessible elements. But the final element as such is a sum(), so I just don't get how I can access it. Probably a very simple problem but I'm just not getting it.

My current function added below returns everything i'm after except the total. i.e. referencing area as res.area works. But request returns the sum as 'sum(`areas`)': 20. So I guess i'm wondering how to reference a sum that has no variable name

```
router.get("/search/:param",function(req,res,next)
{
  req.database.from('animals')
  .select('animals.name', 'areas.lat', 'areas.lng', req.params.area)
  .sum(req.params.area).groupBy('animals.name')
  .leftJoin('areas','req.params.area', 'areas.area')
  .then((rows) => {
    const x = mapFunction(rows)
    res.send({query: req.params.area, result: x})
  })
})

function mapFunction(results) {
  return results.map((res) => 
  ({area: res.area, lat: res.lat, lng: res.lng, total: res.????}))
}
```

Comment: can you post the value of `rows`

Comment: RowDataPacket {
    area: 'Sydney'',
    lat: lattitude,
    lng: longtitude,
    'sum(`areas`)': 20 },

this is what one of the rows returns

Comment: Really weird property, you could access it like `res['sum(areas)']`

Comment: ahh yeap that does, cheers

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to provide usable names for your results. This makes it much easier to reference them later. For example:

```
knex
  .from('animals')
  .select('animals.name', 'areas.lat', 'areas.lng', req.params.area)
  .sum(`${req.params.area} as areaSum`)
```

This way, the sum is available as `areaSum` in your result.